# How to test module in different Magento and PHP versions using CI?

Tags: magento2, module, coding-standards, github, continuous-integration

I have an open-source module in Github and I'd like to automatically test it via CI using the **[Magento Coding Standard](https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard)** and different Magento installations in different PHP versions.
For example:

Magento Enterprise 2.3 + PHP 7.2

Magento Community 2.4 + PHP 7.3

How could I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to implement the Magento Coding Standard, then you can create a Travis config file to set the PHP version that you want to test your module and the Magento version and edition, for example:

**PHP 7.2**

```
- Magento OpenSource (2.3.2, 2.3.3-p1)
- Magento Commerce (2.3.2, 2.3.3-p1)
```

**PHP 7.3**

```
- Magento OpenSource (2.3.3-p1, 2.3.4-p2)
- Magento Commerce (2.3.3-p1, 2.3.4-p2)
```

[image: Magento 2 CI Github]

### Magento Coding Standard

To install the Magento's coding standards in your module first add the Composer package:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Then add these lines in your `composer.json`, I'm considering that you module is inside an `src` folder.

```
...
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "([ $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE -eq 0 ] || vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/)"
        ],
        "php": "vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=./vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility/PHPCompatibility --extensions=php,phtml -d memory_limit=-1 src",
        "lint": "vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 src",
        "fix": "vendor/bin/phpcbf --standard=Magento2 src"
    }
...
```

### Automated tests

In order to set up the automated tests I recommend using Travis CI with Github, to do so, you just need to create these files below. And add your Magento user and password in the Travis panel as **MAGENTO_USERNAME** and **MAGENTO_PASSWORD**.

#### .travis.yml

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - mysql-server-5.6
    - mysql-client-core-5.6
    - mysql-client-5.6
    - postfix

language: php

jobs:
  include:
    - php: 7.2
      env:
        - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.2 MAGENTO_EDITION=community
    - if: type != pull_request
      php: 7.2
      env:
        - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.2 MAGENTO_EDITION=enterprise
    - php: 7.2
      env:
        - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.3-p1 MAGENTO_EDITION=community
    - if: type != pull_request
      php: 7.2
      env:
        - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.3-p1 MAGENTO_EDITION=enterprise
    - php: 7.2
      env:
        - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.4-p2 MAGENTO_EDITION=community
    - if: type != pull_request
      php: 7.2
      env:
        - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.4-p2 MAGENTO_EDITION=enterprise
    - php: 7.3
      env:
          - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.3-p1 MAGENTO_EDITION=community
    - if: type != pull_request
      php: 7.3
      env:
          - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.3-p1 MAGENTO_EDITION=enterprise
    - php: 7.3
      env:
          - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.4-p2 MAGENTO_EDITION=community
    - if: type != pull_request
      php: 7.3
      env:
          - MAGENTO_VERSION=2.3.4-p2 MAGENTO_EDITION=enterprise

before_install:
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" = "false" ]; then composer config -g http-basic.repo.magento.com $MAGENTO_USERNAME $MAGENTO_PASSWORD ; fi
  - echo "{\"http-basic\":{\"repo.magento.com\":{\"username\":\"${MAGENTO_USERNAME}\",\"password\":\"${MAGENTO_PASSWORD}\"}}}" > auth.json
  - composer global require hirak/prestissimo
  - chmod +x ./bin/*
  - ./bin/prepare_php.sh
  - ./bin/before_install.sh

install:
  - composer install --prefer-dist

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.composer/cache

script:
  - ./bin/test_magento.sh
  - vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths ../../magento/magento-coding-standard/
  - vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 --severity=9 src/
```

#### bin/before_install.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p app/etc var

# If no stability configured, do nothing and keep installing the given Magento2 version.
if [[ -z "${MAGENTO_STABILITY}" ]]; then
  VERSION=$MAGENTO_VERSION
else
  # Else, switch explicit version to closest one with ~
  VERSION="~${MAGENTO_VERSION}"
fi

echo "==> Require magento/magento2-base package (Version $VERSION) ..."
composer require magento/magento2-base $VERSION --no-update -q
```

#### bin/prepare_php.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
trap '>&2 echo Error: Command \`$BASH_COMMAND\` on line $LINENO failed with exit code $?' ERR
echo '==> Disabling xdebug, adjusting memory limit to -1.'
phpenv config-rm xdebug.ini
echo 'memory_limit = -1' >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/conf.d/travis.ini
phpenv rehash;
```

#### bin/test_magento.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
trap '>&2 echo Error: Command \`$BASH_COMMAND\` on line $LINENO failed with exit code $?' ERR

# Prepare a full Magento2 project with proper version.
cd ..

# If no stability configured, do nothing and keep installing the given Magento2 version.
if [[ -z "${MAGENTO_STABILITY}" ]]; then
  STABILITY="--stability=stable"
  VERSION="$MAGENTO_VERSION"
else
  # Else, switch explicit version to closest one, and set composer to prefer given stability.
  # Eg. if we want to test 2.3.0 which is in beta, composer will not be able to install it with magento/project-community-edition=2.3.0
  # Proper syntax for installing would be : magento/project-community-edition=2.3.* --stability=beta
  # That's the purpose of the 2 following lines.
  STABILITY="--stability=$MAGENTO_STABILITY"
  VERSION="${MAGENTO_VERSION%.*}.*"
fi

echo "==> Copying Magento2 repository credentials here."
cp "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/auth.json" .

echo "==> Installing Magento 2 $MAGENTO_EDITION (Version $VERSION) ..."
echo "composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-$MAGENTO_EDITION-edition=$VERSION $STABILITY magento"
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-$MAGENTO_EDITION-edition=$VERSION $STABILITY magento --quiet

cd "magento"

# Require the extension to make it usable (autoloading)
echo "==> Requiring extension from the $TRAVIS_BRANCH-dev branch"
composer require --dev "rafaelcg/magento2-quicklink:$TRAVIS_BRANCH-dev" --quiet

echo "==> Installing Magento 2"
mysql -uroot -e 'CREATE DATABASE magento2;'
php bin/magento setup:install -q --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="User" --db-name="magento2"

echo "==> Process upgrade and try to compile..."
php bin/magento setup:upgrade -q
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```